# Insert value in wp_postameta in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

In **wp_postmeta** I have a meta_key **limit_usage_to_x_items** I want to make the meta_value for this field '1'

What SQL line can I use to do this?

My knowledge in SQL is quite basic so I'd appreciate any help

**UPDATE:**

I've been advised to use the following code

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`='1' WHERE `post_id` = '$1' AND `meta_key` = 'limit_usage_to_x_items'
```

When I do this it tells me 0 rows affected. I don't understand why...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value); ?>
```

or

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`='your value' WHERE `post_id` = 'your_post_id' AND `meta_key` = 'your_meta_key'
```

you can use this fucntion or query

for more information you can visit this link :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

Comment: That doesnt help me with mySQL though. I need to do a mass update in MYSQL

Comment: UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`='your value' WHERE `post_id` = 'your_post_id' AND `meta_key` = 'your_meta_key'

Comment: Thanks, the Post_id can be a variable though so it's not 1 specific value. I want to apply it to all posts

Comment: But how would I set post_id as a variable?

Comment: $your_post_id = 1; 
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='your value' WHERE post_id = $your_post_id AND meta_key = 'your_meta_key'

Comment: UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`='1' WHERE `post_id` = '1' AND `meta_key` = 'limit_usage_to_x_items'

Comment: Thanks but your answer still showing 0 rows affected